# mean time to return random walk continuous whit drift to origen

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $S_t$ a random walk with rate $a>0$ on $Z$ that such has a drift in direction of $0$, this is, if $(0,0)\in Z\times[0,\infty)$, and defined a sequence $(S_n, T_n)_{n\in N}$ such that $(S_0, T_0)=(0,0)$ and, for $n\geq1$

$T_n-T_{n-1}=\tau_n\sim Exp(a), \ \ \  \ \ \ S_n-S_{n-1}= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1, &   if  & S_n \leq 0 \\
             -1, &  if & S_n <0 \\
             \end{array}
   \right.$

What is $E(TR_o)$ where $TR_0=\inf\{t>0: S_t=0\}$?

Comment: I don't get what your $T_n$ does in here. Can you be more precise on this point ?

Comment: $T_n$ are the renewal times of random walk

Comment: And where is the stochasticity of $S_n$ ? As far as I understand, its behaviour is deterministic.